# Can I use a different method/function for grouped dataframe?

Tags: r, reshape2, trading, quantitative-finance

I have been following a tutorial where a guy was trying to pull data from wbstats into a dataframe (gross domestic product data).

I think there is something wrong with the last code segment, as I have already installed all of the required libraries (tidyverse, wbstats, data.table, plotly, psych, highcharter, quantmod, TTR, reshape2).

```
population <- wb('SP.POP.TOTL', country = 'countries_only') %>%
  mutate(date = as.numeric(date), value = round(value / 1000000, 2), indicator = 'Population') %>%
  select(-indicatorID)

gdp <- wb('NY.GDP.PCAP.CD', country = 'countries_only') %>%
  mutate(date = as.numeric(date), value = round(value, 2), indicator = 'GDP per Capita') %>%
  select(-indicatorID)

lifeexpectancy <- wb('SP.DYN.LE00.IN', country = 'countries_only') %>%
  mutate(date = as.numeric(date), value = round(value, 2), indicator = 'Life Expectancy') %>%
  select(-indicatorID)

df <- gdp %>%
  rbind(lifeexpectancy) %>%
  rbind(population) %>%
  data.table::dcast(... ~ indicator, value.var = 'value') %>%
  na.omit()
```

Here is the error for the last code segment:

> 

Show in New Window
`wb()` was deprecated in wbstats 1.0.0.
Please use `wb_data()` instead.`wb()` was deprecated in wbstats 1.0.0.
Please use `wb_data()` instead.`wb()` was deprecated in wbstats 1.0.0.
Please use `wb_data()` instead.The dcast generic in data.table has been passed a data.frame and will attempt to redirect to the reshape2::dcast; please note that reshape2 is deprecated, and this redirection is now deprecated as well. Please do this redirection yourself like reshape2::dcast(.). In the next version, this warning will become an error.

> 

The problem is that when I actually try to modify wb for wb_data it immediately returns me an error with the mutate values [`rlang::last_error()`]. I would really like to use this function, but perhaps there is a better way to it with tidyr. Any ideas?

Comment: The first piece  is a friendly warning and ther eis no issue in that.  Without a reproducible example, it is diffiuclt to understanad the error.  Change the `rbind` to `bind_rows` and also use `pivot_wider` instead of `dcast` i.e. `tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = 'indicator', values_from = 'value')`

Comment: When I run the chunk it doesn't show any data at all. It just gives me the warning and that's it.

Comment: i.e. try `bind_rows(gdp, lifeexpectancy, population) %>% tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = 'indicator', values_from = 'value')`

Comment: warning is fine, but the error is the one that may be the problem  You are assigning to an object `df <-`.  So, it won't show anything on the console unless you do `head(df)` or `str(df)`

Comment: the `dcast` warning is informative as `data.table::dcast` expects the input objects to be data.table and not data.frame

Comment: I went with `df <- gdp %>%
  bind_rows(gdp, lifeexpectancy, population) %>% tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = 'indicator', values_from = 'value') %>% 
  na.omit()
  print(df)` And it returns only <dbl [2]>'s & <dbl [1]>'s for these lists: Life Expectancy, GDP Per Capita and Population. The other column names are fine (date, chrs).

Comment: That is because you have duplicates

Comment: Please check the solutioin below where I added a row sequence to take care of the duplicates

Comment: Also, you are binding `gdp` twice `gdp %>%   bind_rows(gdp,` resulting in duplicates which is not the solution I posted in the comments above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need a tidy version, instead of `rbind`, use `bind_rows` and then change the `dcast` to `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df <- gdp %>%
    bind_rows(., lifeexpectancy, population)  %>%
    mutate(rn = rowid(indicator)) %>% # in case of any duplicates
    tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = 'indicator', values_from = 'value') %>% 
    na.omit() %>%
    select(-rn)
```

Comment: This one didn't do it but the one you gave me in the comments apparently worked: `bind_rows(gdp, lifeexpectancy, population) %>% tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = 'indicator', values_from = 'value') %>%
  na.omit()` It showed me the appropriate data. Thanks so much my friend. R has always been a steep learning curve for me. :)

Comment: @gab7777 when you are doing in `%>%` i.e. `gdp %>% bind_rows(lifeexpectancy, population)` is enough or if you want to add the `gdp` the data coming out from the lhs of %>% is `.` i.e. `gdp %>% bind_rows(., lifeexpectancy, population)` when you are adding `gdp` again, it will be `bind_rows(gdp, gdp, lifeexpectancy, population)` similar to your code in `%>%`